# Select from a select mysql

Tags: mysql

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this:

```
SELECT
  Cont, COUNT(id) 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM protable
  WHERE MATCH (ProdTitulo) AGAINST ('art' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) 
GROUP BY Cont;
```

The problem is when I try to use fetch array on that I got:"Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

The select inside the parentheses (line 3) seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an alias for the subquery:

```
SELECT Cont, COUNT(id) 
FROM 
( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM protable 
   WHERE MATCH (ProdTitulo) AGAINST ('art' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AS t   -- <---------- You are missing this
GROUP BY Cont
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me a lot. I should learn (the reason) why I need to put an alias.